# Why am I getting "Invalid Envelope" errors in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

Sometimes the response of callable CloudFunctions 
[cloud_functions 0.0.5](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_functions#-installing-tab-) throws `CloudFunctionGenericException`
with "Invalid Envelope" message.

This seems to happen for no specific reason, 
and nothing is logged to the Firebase Cloud Function Logs.

This occours rarely (once each 10 times approx), 
but breaks the app logic.

Why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting this error every time, don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is still under development, please [report your use case here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).